# What determines the size of the message in the algorithm RSA?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I read about RSA algorithm and How it work? But I don't understand some think.I ask for plaintext length 
Why specify the size of the plaintext in the 64-bit algorithm rsa?
also
Is plaintext length is related key length?
I need any suggested to understand this idea?

Comment: RSA is not a 64-bit algorithm.

Comment: OK IS NOT 64 BIT? THEN TELL ME RELATED KEY LENGTH TO PLAINTEXT LENGTH IN RSA?

Answer (score 2):

When using the RSA algorithm, the plaintext size cannot be larger than the modulus of the key. For example, a 2048-bit RSA key cannot operate on plaintext that is larger than 2048 bits (or 256 bytes).

This restriction also needs to consider padding, which normally adds several bytes. For example, PKCS#1 padding typically adds at least 11 bytes to the plaintext, meaning the largest plaintext is then 245 bytes (or smaller).